# Unable To Run Jar With Gradle HttpClient Dependecy

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to run a jar file after I build with gradle in IntelliJ but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

My build.gradle looks like such:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

I've checked the dependencies for httpcomponents and commons-codec in my module settigns in IntelliJ.

Source code:

```
package com.jshah;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import static org.apache.http.HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT;


public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "http://reddit.com/api/trending_subreddits";

        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

            request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just build you project by calling: gradle build (without add any additional plugin, except java)? If so, there are no httpclient classes in your jar. You need to use either [FatJar](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) or [Copy dependencies](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-gather-all-my-projects-dependencies-into-a-folder/7146) to build your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend your jar task to collect dependencies and pack them up, but note that this is not a preferred solution. I use it only for some small apps or testing. strongly suggest using plugins.

```
jar {
archiveName = 'Name.jar'

manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'your main',
            'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
            'Implementation-Version': project.version
}

from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
}
```